# nvdia 525, steam proton, and vulkan. my games are freezing on start up to the point I have to restart my computer

Tags: nvidia, games, steam

On ubuntu mate 22.04
Processor: AMD ryzen 7 2700X eight-core Process
Graphics card: GeForce RTX 2060 super
Running Nvidia driver 525 open (proprietary,tested)

The game I'm using as my test game is Hollowknight.
I am very new to Linux and unbutu so let me know if any further information is needed and I will do my best to find it. I am just very lost and want to play my games without having to give up on Linux and go back to windows

Comment: Have you tried the non-"open" version of the 525 driver?